# Symfony 1.3: the .css and images are not loaded in production

Tags: symfony1

I have deployed my symfony app into a shared server. The problem: for example, the images and the .css of the default page that says

```
ok
Symfony Project Created
Congratulations! You have successfully created your symfony project.

Project setup successful
...
```

are not loaded.

I read [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/03-Running-Symfony#chapter_03_sub_configuring_a_shared_host_server) but it's not enough for me..

What should I do?

Regards

Javi

Comment: You aren't meant to see those images/styles/pages in production.

Comment: I mean I don't see those images/styles/pages in production.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to symlink from your web directory to the symfony data directory. In a standard Symfony install, with Symfony inside of your lib/vendor directory, it would look like this:

```
ln -s ../lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf/ sf
```

Alternatively, you can add an Alias for sf in your Apache config.